# How to add space/blank option in selectInput in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use selectInput function and in drop down wanted to add space/ blank option for user to select.
example:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('selalpha', "Select Alpha", choices=c("", "a", "b", "c"), selected ="a")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
  }
)
```

In Choice parameter of this function, i am passing a vector such as
`choice = c("", "a","b","c")`. but while running i am only seeing `a,b,c` option in dropdown.

The dropdown needs to have a default value of `a` but the user can have option to change that to spaces from dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

A small trick will do this.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('selalpha', "Select Alpha", choices = c("\a", "a", "b", "c"), selected = "a")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

This gives you a proper empty space which will allow you to select.
Another option : use `\n` instead of `\a`.
In this case it is a little hard to check in `selectInput` output but a blank will come for sure. 
So to confirm this use `choices = c("\nz", "a", "b", "c")` then you could see just `z` in the dropdown choices.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using ""(quotes without spaces), " "(quotes with a space between them).

Comment: any other option, this workaround will need lots of handling in the code.

Comment: Maybe, i mean maybe you can try find and replace, find for "" and replace it with " ".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pickerInput`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.7.2/topics/pickerInput) from the package `shinyWidgets` with minimal change to your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    # pickerInput instead of selectInput
    pickerInput('selalpha', "Select Alpha", choices=c("", "a", "b", "c"), selected ="a")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
  }
)
```

`pickerInput` also has a lot of customization options.